# Projectile motion - ball hit 180m/s at 45 degrees, what is the hang time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Assuming no air resistance etc, how long is the ball in the air for?

This is actually part of a longer question concerning the ball trajectory on different planets but I think there must be an easier way than what I am doing.

This is what I have - 
$$Y -Direction$$ $$v_y=u_y+a_yt$$
$$0=u_y-9.8t$$
$$u_y=9.8t$$
$$u_y=sin45\cdot{}v_0$$
Where $v_o$ is the inital velocity of the ball 
$$X-Direction$$
$$x=x_0+u_xt+\frac{1}{2}a_xt^2$$
$$180=0+u_xt+\frac{1}{2}0_xt^2$$
$$u_x=\frac{180}{t}$$
$$u_x=cos45\cdot{}v_0$$

From this I substitute to find t. 
$$9.8t=sin45\cdot{}v_0$$
$$v_0=\frac{9.8t}{sin45}$$
$$\frac{180}{t}=cos45\cdot{}v_0$$
$$V_0=\frac{180}{cos45t}$$
$$\therefore\frac{9.8t}{sin45}=\frac{180}{cos45t}$$
$$180=\frac{9.8t\cdot{}cos45t}{sin45}$$
The $sin45$ and $cos45$ cancel out
$$180=9.8t^2$$
$$t^2=\frac{180}{9.8}$$
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{180}{9.8}}$$
$$t\approx4.29s$$

However I can't help but think this is too long winded and I am going about it the wrong way, especially considering it is exam prep where it will only be worth 1 mark out of 40.

Comment: How is this "off topic"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution you seem to make the assumption that the terminal velocity in the y-direction is zero. This produces the wrong answer. This is how I would solve the problem:

First, let's note that the initial velocity in both x- and y-direction are the same (due to the $45^{\circ}$ angle). Let's call it $v$. The distance traveled in the x-direction, $d$, when the ball hit's the ground is given by:

$$
d=vt
$$

where $t$ is the time of flight.

When the ball hits the ground, its velocity in the y-direction will be $-v$. This means that its velocity has changed by $2v$ (or rather by $-2v$). Hence we also have:

$$
2v=gt
$$

Substituting for $v$ gives:

$$
d=\frac{gt^2}{2}
$$

which solved for $t$ gives:

$$
t=\sqrt{\frac{2d}{g}}=\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot 180}{9.8}}\approx 6.06\,\rm{s}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you can't directly use the formulae which are generally being used during study of this chapter, there is another method for doing so:

You can find actual (resultant) initial velocity like,

u = sqrt(Ux^2 + Uy^2)   metre/second

now if use of formula is allowed, you can find "hang time" (called "Time of flight", too sometimes) by,

t = 2usinTHEETA/(g) second

Derivation of above formula:
Let,
h = total vertical displacement (= 0)
then,
h = Uyt - .5gt^2

knowing that Uy = UsinTHEETA

h = UsinTHEETA(t)- .5g(t^2)
0 = t(UsinTHEETA - .5g(t))
0 = UsinTHEETA - .5g(t)
.5g(t) = UsinTHEETA
t = 2UsinTHEETa / (g)   sec

Note: Extremely sorry for not formatting my ans.